# Cargar contenido en un AlertDialog

Tags: android, alertdialog

Me encuentro tratando de cargar una imagen en un *ImageView* de Android obtenida desde la cámara directamente, todo esto en un **onActivityResult**. La imagen se obtiene bien, el problema es que estoy tratando de integrarla a un *Custom AlertDialog* en el cual tengo el campo pero no encuentro como obtener el objeto y poder editarlo.

Intento obtener directamente el contenido con *findViewById* pero me indica que trabajo sobre un punto nulo y al obtenerlo como *view.findViewById* no hace cambio alguno.

```
        Bundle extras = data.getExtras();
        Bitmap imageBitmap = (Bitmap) extras.get("data");
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.add_pet_photo_dialog, null);
        ImageView imageView = view.findViewById(R.id.add_photo_imageview);
        imageView.setImageBitmap(imageBitmap);
        builder.setView(View.inflate(this, R.layout.add_pet_photo_dialog, null));
        builder.setPositiveButton("YES", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                System.out.println("----> YES");
            }
        });
        builder.setNegativeButton("NO", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                System.out.println("---> NO");
            }
        });
        builder.create();
        builder.show();
```

Answer (score 0):

Incursionando un poco en los métodos de la clase he obtenido la respuesta, la forma de obtener el contenido es directamente desde el dialogo.

```
AlertDialog builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
                .setView(R.layout.add_pet_photo_dialog).setPositiveButton("YES", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        System.out.println("----> YES");
                    }
                }).setNegativeButton("NO", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        System.out.println("---> NO");
                    }
                })
                .create();
        builder.show();
        ImageView imageView = builder.findViewById(R.id.add_photo_imageview);
        imageView.setImageBitmap(imageBitmap);
```

de esta forma obtengo el objeto ya instanciado.